# React Textfield onChange capture previous event.target.value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the value of the Textfield as user types, both when typing or deleting. Currently I have:

```
<TextField
  autoFocus
  id="Numbers"
  label="num"
  type="number"
  fullWidth
  onChange={handleChange}
/>;
```

My on `handleChange` is:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const val = event.target.value;
  setNumbers(val);
  console.log(numbers);
};
```

However, my number is always the previous input rather than the one the user currently has typed, what is the issue here?

Comment: This is a dupe of something...looking for it.

Comment: I've closed it to discourage more answers, but the dupe I have selected may not be the most ideal. This same question gets asked 10 times a day on SO - setState isn't sync.

Answer (score 0):

`setNumbers` doesn't immediately update `numbers`, within the change handler you only have access to the value of `numbers` at the point the change handler was created.

`setNumbers` will trigger a new render of your component, in which `numbers` will have the new value.

If you want to something with the new value, just use `val`

Answer (score 0):

`setNumbers` is an asynchronous method, so the log command will be put in the call stack first and actually run before you set a new value.
To check if your code work, try using `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(numbers);
}, [numbers]);
```

Ref:
https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff